# Is it possible to use OAuth with the Salesforce Cloud Connector Streaming operations?

Tags: oauth, streaming, salesforce, mule

I want to use the Salesforce streaming operation subscribe topic. It says in the docs that it supports oauth and has an attribute for accessTokenId see here:http://mulesoft.github.com/salesforce-connector/mule/sfdc-config-with-oauth.html#subscribe-topic

However this erros whenever I try to run my flow:

cvc-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'accessTokenId' is not allowed to appear in element 'sfdc:subscribe-topic'.

In MuleStudio it says im using Salesforce v5.0 and mule.module-sfdc-5.1.3.jar.

Also if this is possible how am I meant to get the accesstokenid as the the subscribe-topic is a message-source?

Comment: The latest version of the SFDC module is 5.3.0 (see https://repository.mulesoft.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/org/mule/modules/mule-module-sfdc/5.3.0/). You may want to upgrade first.

Comment: Upodated to that version and still the same error. Maybe the documentation is wrong?

Comment: I've looked at the schema for the connector and can't find `accessTokenId` as a valid attribute for `subscribe-topic`. Then I tend to think that the doc is wrong. Open an issue in GitHub.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also took a look at this. It would appear @Source's do not support OAuth atm. Just @Processor's. Looking at the Salesforce Connector source, the method is marked @OAuthProtected and the LongPollingTransport is set up to use the required OAuth headers. I guess the DevKit only generates the required fields if the method is an @Processor. See: http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/OAuth+Migration+Guide

I have raised an issue against the connector: https://github.com/mulesoft/salesforce-connector/issues/55

As for the second question. If and when OAuth is supported or fixed for this. The best way I can see to dynamically pass an accesstoken to the message source is to usethe dynamic flows module. More info here: http://blogs.mulesoft.org/adding-flows-dynamically/. Failing that you will have to dynamically genere=ate and start the flow yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete this token, but for this you need configuration the Org Salesforce: Go to setup->Security Controls->Network Access

in salesforce we have option to enter IP range for the profile, so that way when user assigned with that profile(IP restricted profile) and try to login into system then only User Name and Password is required.

So this way User can login into System without security Toke. TO set Login IP Ranges for Profile:

1. Go to profile detail page.(User can see 'Login IP Ranges' related
   list on Profile detail page.)
2. Go to Login IP Ranges related list of profile.
3. Click New button(To Enter the IP Range)
4. Enter IP Range: Start IP Address: 0.0.0.0 End IP Address:
   255.255.255.255 This is generic IP range, User can access salesforce account from anywhere. You can set the Start and End IP range based
   on you company policy.